# Как удалить компилятор rust

Tags: rust

Я никак не могу удалить компилятор rust ..

Comment: а на какой ОС пытаетесь? если на виндовс - ищите деинсталлятор, на линуксе - соответстующий `apt remove rustc` (для убунту) или `dnf remove rust` (для федоры). Ну и cargo наверно нужно.

Comment: `brew uninstall rust` — macos.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл решение.

(Оно точно работает на windows)

Нужно ввести в командную строку
“rustup self uninstall”